# Telegram и WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, telegram

[image: Пример!]

Может кто сталкивался? Есть канал в telegram. Есть сайт на WordPress. Задача стоит такая, сделать посты автоматические из WordPress (новые записи, статьи, новости) в канал telegram . Пример, как нужно реализовать, показываю на картинке (моб. версия показана в img).

Если кто сталкивался с данным вопросом, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Да плагинов вроде достаточно, например https://www.frip.in/telegram-wordpress-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

1. зарегистрировать бота телеграмм
2. добавить его в канал с правами администратора
3. написать самому/купить/найти готовое решение на WP для автопостинга (бот постит в канал сообщения)
4. чтоб была красивая кнопка "посмотреть": зарегистрировать для вашего домена шаблон мгновенного просмотра в телеграмм (https://instantview.telegram.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Для меня отлично работает https://wordpress.org/plugins/wptelegram/ .
Установка и подключение очень простое, как подключить к каналну написано в самом плагине на странице настроек в пенели администрирования.

Answer (score 0):

Вот готовое решение для автопостинга в телеграм постов с WP
https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/telegram-for-wp/
Ознакомьтесь, и будет вам счастье)